# Regex Get the previous sentence based on period or new line, before the occurance of a word

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm trying to make a regex statement that can get the *previous sentence* before the occurrence of "[bbcode]" but is flexible enough to work in different scenarios.

For example, the previous sentence may be defined as following a period. However, it may simply be on a new line. I cannot use ^$ to define start or end of line as this may not always be the case.

**Whole test string:**

```
Example 1:
Blah blah blah. THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE SELECTED [bbcode]

Example 2:
THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE SELECTED [bbcode]

Example 3:
A trick sentence. And another. THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE SELECTED


[bbcode]
```

**Expected matches:**
All three instances of THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE SELECTED should be matched.

This is the regex I tried:

```
'/(?:\.)(.+)(\[bbcode\])/gUs'
```

This fails when sentence is on a new line as in Example 2.

Link to
[Regex Interrupter using my Regex](https://regex101.com/r/JYUqbl/1)

I have tried negative lookbehinds to no avail. The strings "THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE SELECTED" should get picked up in all three examples.

Picking up surrounding spaces is ok because I can trim it later.

**Challenges:**

- The entire supplied code must be tested as one string. This is how the data will be supplied and will likely contain many random spaces, new lines etc which the regex must consider.
- It is likely impossible to prepare / sanitize the string first, as the string will likely be very poorly formatted without proper punctuation. Contracting the string could cause unintended run-on sentences.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output? I now understand that your 3 examples are all part of one string, but I still don't know what output you expect.

Comment: I added expected output along with some other notes. My regex link also shows the correct data breing partially matched.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with basic PHP functions. Something like this:

```
function extractSentence($string)
{
    $before = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '[bbcode]'));
    return trim(substr($before, strrpos($before, '.')), "\n .");
}
```

The advantage is that it is easy to understand, doesn't take much time to develop and can more easily be changed if that need arises.

See: [PHP Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/CgDB7)

Comment: That's a very interesting solution, however in my supplied string I should have mentioned that the overall structure is important to test as one string. This is because of new lines, spaces, carriage returns etc which may be encountered all around the target match in many ways. In your working solution however, the target match is isolated in tidy one line strings.

Comment: @RobertIannicca I have to give you credit.  I still do not understand the question. I tried to edit the question in an attempt to make it intelligible, but...  I do prefer str_pos() solutions rather than regex.

Comment: I'm sorry it's confusing and I tried to explain with my edits. Basically the test string is one large string containing new lines and spaces (it is forum post data from a WYSIWYG editor which tend to produce tons of poorly formatted data.) The regex must find the previous sentence, whether that means a phrase is following the end period of a previous sentence, or, it's a phrase on a new line. In all three examples, the phrase "This sentence should be selected" should get matched by the regex. As the examples show, in each case that is technically the "sentence" before the occurrence of "bbcode

Answer (score 0):

1. Match and release an optional space ( `*\K`) then
2. Lazily match one or more non-dot characters (`[^.]+?`) then
3. Lookahead for zero or more whitespace characters followed by the bbcode tag (`(?=\s+\[bbcode])`)
4. Make the pattern case-insensitive if the bbcode might be uppercase (`i`)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NsMm5))

```
$tests = [
    'Blah blah blah. THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE SELECTED [bbcode] text',
    'THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE SELECTED [bbcode] text',
    'A trick sentence. And another. THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE SELECTED


[bbcode]] text'
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_export(preg_match('/ *\K[^.]+?(?=\s+\[bbcode])/i', $test, $m) ? $m[0] : 'no match');
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```